# Pointer to NSMutableArray returns Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I am trying to use a `NSMutableArray` that I have created in `ViewController` in an `ViewController2`. But it is just returning `nil`.

Here is my ViewController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *total_hours;
```

Here is my ViewController.m file:

```
 total_hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

I also add object. Use `NSLog` to display that this have actually been added, so that is working. But now I try to use `NSLog` to display them again in the other `ViewController2`.

Here is my ViewController2.h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)NSMutableArray*total_hours_copy;
```

here is my ViewController2.m file:

```
#import "TimelisteViewController.h"
// some auto enabled code
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    TimelisteViewController *test = [[TimelisteViewController alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *total_hours_copy = test.total_hours;

    NSLog(@"%@", [total_hours_copy objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: In which method do you initialize you array total_hours ?

Comment: In ViewDidLoad:
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        total_hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        dates_times = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view,      typically from a nib.
    }

Comment: Before answering your question I'm curious to know what is your goal...

Comment: My goal is as follows: I have to textfiels that you type into. When you hit a button an value is written to this Mutable Array. I have another View (in storyboard) That i would like to display this array in. How can i get this array in the other Viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2):

Your question implies that you create the array in ViewController and want to later pass it to ViewController2. However, in ViewController2's viewDidLoad method, you create a new instance of ViewController. So that's a problem.

It would be easier to answer your question if :

1. You indicated in which method total_hours is initialized.
2. How control is transferred between the 2 controllers.

Comment: I thought i needed to create a new instasce (copy) of the viewcontroller to accsess the array thats made in it?

Comment: @Crytrus If you have a new instance it will be empty, and especially the array will be nil, since you are creating it in view did load. But remember that 2 instances are 2 different objects. If I forget my keys in my wife's care I DON'T expect them to be in my car, they are 2 different cars.

Comment: Paul Lalonde is right, u are creating new object of your first ViewController, so u will get that to be nil becz ur array initialization is in viewDidLoad of your first ViewController. U can put array initialization in "init" method or custom "init" method of first ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing you array in the right place. viewDidLoad is only called when the view controller is shown, not at the initialization.
You could override init method in your view controller :

```
- (void)init{
    [super init];
    total_hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

However this is not a usual pattern, and i won't recommend it. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but i believe it would be best to initialize you array in your viewcontroller2 and pass it after  to your newly initialize controller.

```
TimelisteViewController *test = [[TimelisteViewController alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *total_hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Add your data in the array
test.total_hours = total_hours;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that **Paul Lalonde** has made good considerations, if you need to pass the array from a view controller to another you can follow two ways.

- Create a singleton class that would share the array (in this way each controller can access to that singleton and hence to that array)
- Inject the array from a controller to another (preferred way since it allows decoupling components and having less application rigidity)

So, following the second solution, from `ViewController1` you inject the array like the following snippet. Now both controller will share the same array. Modifications made by one controller will be visible to the other and vice versa...

```
ViewController2 secondController = // alloc-init here…
secondController.sharedArray = [self sharedArray];
```

where `ViewController2` would have a property like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* sharedArray;
```

Then, for example, within its `viewDidLoad` or wherever you want you can say

```
[self.sharedController add…]
```

Said this, what it your application flow? For example, is `ViewController2` a controller that is displayed after `ViewController1` through a `UINavigationController` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`total_hours_copy` is a local variable in your `viewDidLoad` method, not a property!. Change your code to

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    TimelisteViewController *test = [[TimelisteViewController alloc]init];
    self.total_hours_copy = test.total_hours;
    // or maybe self.total_hours_copy = [test.total_hours copy];

    NSLog(@"%@", [total_hours_copy objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

Comment: Ah! think i get it now. But do i do this in the first viewcontroller or in the second(where i try to inport the array)?